# Are there already spacecraft equipped with RAD5500 processors?

Tags: radiation, flight-computer, radiation-hardening

Just stumbled across RAD750s successor, the [RAD5500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAD5500).
Are there already spacecraft using this Chip, or are there plans for this chip? Looks pretty new!

Comment: related by reference only [What makes Insight's RAD750 processor so radiation resistant? (compared to 1998 iMac's PowerPC 750)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50470/12102)

Comment: just asked in meta: ["upgrade" the new [rad750] tag to something like [radiation-hardening] or "downgrade" it to the cornfield?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2983/12102)

Comment: just asked in meta: ["upgrade" the new rad750 tag to something like radiation-hardening or "downgrade" it to the cornfield, or combine with shielding, or...?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2983/12102)

Comment: The RAD5545 is a power-hungry device (20 watts), thereby generating a lot of heat. Dissipating heat in spacecraft is nontrivial. It will only be used on large spacecraft that need a lot of computing power. Those are few and far between, and many are highly classified. Since it takes well over five years to design, develop, and deploy such spacecraft, and since that line of computers is only five years old, I suspect the answer to *Are there already spacecraft equipped with RAD5500 processors?* is not yet.